# Compare Two Rows and Find the Difference Between Them Which is In The Second Column?

Tags: ms-access

I have a table that has the following data:

```
ID      Name       LastName
1      William     Johns
2      John        Adam
4      William     Smith
3      Mark        Stephan
```

I want to Find all those records that their Names are the same but there Last Names are different. so the result will be something like this:

```
ID      Name       LasName
1       William     Johns
2       William     Smith
```

What would be the MS. Access Query or method to find all these records?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could rephrase it like this:

> Return every row for which another row exists with the same `Name` and a different `LastName`

which is very easy to translate to SQL if you are familiar with the EXISTS predicate:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  YourTable AS t1
WHERE
  EXISTS
  (
    SELECT
      *
    FROM
      YourTable AS t2
    WHERE
      t2.Name = t1.Name
      AND t2.LastName <> t1.LastName
  )
;
```

Answer (score 4):

An alternative way, under the assumption that there are *no* repeated (Name, LastName) pairs, is the following.

First select all the names that appear more than once, and create a Query out of them.

This can be done with Access GUI by means of:

[image: Design View with names that appear more than once]

Once this is done, create another Query that `JOINs` this query with the original table, using `Name` as the common column:

[image: Design View with the multiple names together with LastNames]

And this is what you finally get (starting from your data)

[image: Data view names / lastNames]

The corresponding SQL:

`NamesThatAppearMultipleTimes` query:

```
SELECT t.Name
FROM t
GROUP BY t.Name
HAVING (((Count(t.ID))>1));
```

and `NamesThatAppearMultipleTimes-and-LastNames`

```
SELECT t.ID, t.Name, t.LastName
FROM NamesThatAppearMultipleTimes 
     INNER JOIN t ON NamesThatAppearMultipleTimes.Name = t.Name
ORDER BY t.Name, t.LastName;
```